# Laravel link a controller function using xmlhttp.open

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-5

I am new to laravel 5 and I want to know how can I use `xmlhttp.open` to send a `GET` request.

Here is what supposed to be my javascript code:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET", "reg_validation?field=" + field + "&query=" + query, false);
```

So how can I link that one to a function inside a controller and return its value with `xmlhttp.responseText`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a new route for this request :

```
Route::get('reg_validation', 'YourController@yourAction');
```

Then use the return in your action :

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input; //Import 'Input' class in the top of controller

function yourAction(){
   $field = Input::get("field");
   $query = Input::get("query");

   return $field.' -- '.$query;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I got another error saying `FatalErrorException in Controller.php line 15:
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Input' not found`